# Browser compatibility of Polymer

Tags: cross-browser, polymer, compatibility, polymer-1.0

I am starting to use Polymer 1.0: the only thing I tried is a simple template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"></link>
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

        <title>Polymer test1</title>
    </head>
    <body unresolved>

        <dom-module id="pres-test">

        <template>

            <content></content>

            <p>This is my name:<h3>{{name}}</h3></p>
            <iron-icon icon="star" hidden="{{!star}}"></iron-icon>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100"></img>

        </template>

    </dom-module>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is:'pres-test',
            properties:{
                name:String,
                star:Boolean
            }
        });
    </script>

    <pres-test name="withStar" star>
        <h1>Example1:</h1>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/180" alt="image"></img>
    </pres-test>

    <pres-test name="withoutStar">
        <h2>Example:</h2>
        <img src="http://placesheen.com/100/100"></img>
        <p>No star icon :()</p>
    </pres-test>


    </body>
</html>
```

This code works fine on Chrome and Opera, except that even if I don't put the boolean star in pres-test, it still shows the star.

In Firefox and IE, it just shows the h1 and img in the pres-test.

In Safari it seems that it doesn't understand the tags like dom-module, template or pres-test, since it first displays what is in the dom-module, then what is in pres-test, without adapting to the variables.

I looked for the compatibility of Polymer, but I only found it for the version 0.5.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just not compatible with these browsers?

Comment: Are you using the `webcomponents-lite.js` polyfill? e.g. `<script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>` Also, make sure you are defining your custom elements in a separate file and then importing it into your page.

Comment: I was just using webcomponents.min.js, I added webcomponents-lite.min.js. Now Firebug shows TypeError: t.log.split is not a function. I have the elements in the same html page there, because it was just a short test, but it can affect the display of the browsers?

Comment: Interesting... would you mind putting up the code for the whole page? I wonder if there's something that the snippet is leaving out of the picture. Also, yes, because the polyfill is not synchronous (unlike native HTML imports), this can affect display in browsers without native support.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I completed the code. About the browsers, ok, but I guess it shouldn't be a problem for Firefox, or even IE right?

Comment: It seems to be what's preventing the element from being displayed. Also, I just updated my code and fixed the property definitions - the star property should work as intended now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only Chrome supports having custom element definitions inline in your main document. Other browsers currently do not have full and proper implementations of the new and upcoming standard.

Take the `pres-test` element definition and move it into its own HTML file, then import it.

Also, you only need to import one of the webcomponents.js polyfills - and for Polymer 1.0, you'll want to use `webcomponents-lite.js`.

All said and done you'll have two files:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <link rel="import" href="pres-test.html">

        <title>Polymer test1</title>
    </head>
    <body unresolved>

    <pres-test name="withStar" star>
        <h1>Example1:</h1>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/180" alt="image"></img>
    </pres-test>

    <pres-test name="withoutStar">
        <h2>Example:</h2>
        <img src="http://placesheen.com/100/100"></img>
        <p>No star icon :()</p>
    </pres-test>


    </body>
</html>
```

`pres-test.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<dom-module id="pres-test">

    <template>

        <content></content>

        <p>This is my name:<h3>{{name}}</h3></p>
        <iron-icon icon="star" style$="{{getStarStyle(star)}}"></iron-icon>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100"></img>

    </template>

</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is:'pres-test',
        properties:{
            name: {
                type: String
            },
            star: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false
            }
        },
        getStarStyle: function(star) {
            return star ? '' : 'display: none';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I used the example from the Polymer-Project website, but your version works. Thank you!