# Polymer Dart Stagehand - how to use webcomponents?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

First, it would be really nice if the stagehand "reversed text" Dart Polymer default example worked in all browsers.

Reading this > [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787039/browser-compatibility-of-polymer), I changed the example's index.html to include the webcomponents line:

```
<body unresolved>
   <main-app></main-app>
     <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
     <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
     <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

I also downloaded the [webcomponents](http://webcomponents.org/) zip and copied the js file to my project web folder and referenced it there. Clearly, I don't know what I'm doing. Do I need to change or add something to pubspec dependencies?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

There is the Dart `web_components` package that wraps web-components polyfills for Dart. Stagehand automatically adds the dependency to your `pubspec.yaml`. 
After you run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` you can find the scripts in the `packages/web_components/` directory.

Just add

```
  <script src="web_componentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
```

in the head of your entry page (not after the Dart script tag as shown in your question).

Stagehand is a community project. Please file an issue in the GitHub repo to add the script tag or create a pull request with the necessary changes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. A step forward! It works in Firefox, but still not in Edge. I will try my entire project with Firefox next. Cheers, s

Comment: What doesn't work in Edge? Some error message, some misbehavior?

Comment: I'm running the stagehand reversed text example. I've uploaded it as my webpage "acsumama.com". In Edge, it's  blank screen. S

Comment: I don't have Edge available on my Linux system. Can you please check if the `<body>` tag still has the `unresolved` attribute set after load?

Comment: Hi Gunter. Yes it does (viewing in Edge's developer tools) It has unresolved="". Steve

Comment: I don't know Edge. Can you edit the HTML in developer tools? Please try to remove the `unresolved` attribute and report back if this makes the content visible.

Comment: I removed the unresolved, rebuilt and uploaded, but the content is still not visible. (OK in Firefox). S

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas, I don't have Edge/IE running (on Linux).

Comment: No problem, thanks. I guess it will eventually work when things get more mature.